# How to paste images from clipboard in Safari

Tags: safari, macos

How do you paste an image from your clipboard in to websites/forms which support pasting, in Safari?

For example, in Chrome, I can take a screenshot using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and then use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste that image in to a Facebook chat. This is very convenient. However, I don't seem to be able to do the same in Safari. Manually right clicking, and selecting paste doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

This is known issue with the current release of Safari.

But pasting images from the clipboard is now working properly in the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) which means the fix *should* be coming to the public release version of Safari shortly.

FYI, You can go ahead and use the tech preview version alongside your regular Safari install without disrupting anything.

**EDIT**: Safari 10.1 was released today and fixes this issue.

**EDIT #2**: It seems to only work with some source applications but not others. For example, I can select and copy sections of web pages w/images and paste them into Gmail no problem (Safari to Safari). I can also copy text+images from Evernote to Gmail. But... the same doesn't seem to work when TextEdit or Notes is the source.

[Relevant bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49141)

Comment: Just checked Safari's version and it's 10.1.1 and I still can't paste image in gmail email.

Comment: yes for me also it doesnt work on facebook using safari 10.1.2

Comment: Frustrating. In addition to Facebook, this continues to be a common issue in: Google Hangouts chat inside Gmail, Slack, Stackoverflow/Stackexchange editor and other similar Markdown editors that handle images.

Comment: Try the latest Safari Technology Preview as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is still an active bug (or possibly misfeature depending on your perspective). Support for pasting ([WebKit bug #49141](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49141)) is apparently implemented in both WebKit upstream and Safari, but it seems to have been done so in a way that is not compatible with anything ([WebKit bug #170449](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170449)).

The BugZilla for the latter bug suggests that there is an associated radar within Apple about this.

In other words, I guess the straight answer to your question is "wait for either Apple to conform to what everyone else is doing, or for support for Safari's way of doing things to percolate everywhere", whichever happens first.

**Edit**: It seems to consistently work for me in Safari Technology Preview (Release 52 (Safari 11.2, WebKit 13606.1.9.3.1)) under High Sierra, including on both Trello and Facebook.

Comment: With current Safari (11.0.3 (13604.5.6) on Hight Sierra), I cannot paste images into cards at https://trello.com – but it does work in Safari Technology Preview (release 51). I have not tested pasting into Facebook chats.

Comment: Can confirm, pasting on Facebook chats works on Release 53 (Safari 11.2, WebKit 13606.1.11.2) with High Sierra. Finally!

Comment: Safari 13.0.3, pasting into snipboard.io -- an alert message is triggered, indicating possibly less than 100% compatibility -- but upon closing the alert message, the clipboard contents do appear on the website. So it appears that even though the WebKit bugs you refer to have now been RESOLVED FIXED, there may still be a niggling issue there. Am chasing up the clipboard.io folks to see if they can shed any light on it.