# Copy and paste image in Safari

Tags: safari, graphics, copy-paste

I have issues copying an image from website into clipboard and then pasting it on another website in Safari (e.g. Messenger or Facebook). When I click on an image with two-click and select `Copy image` option and then paste it into another place, I'm getting the image URL instead of the image itself.

I found [THIS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208637/how-to-paste-images-from-clipboard-in-safari) thread, but it does not resolve my issue, since I still face it although having the latest OS (Mojave 10.14.1) installed, as well as the latest Safari (12.0.1).

I would greatly appreciate any help, cause I don't want to switch to another browser.

Comment: I usually just drag the image from the web page onto the Desktop

Comment: What I want to achieve is paste it into another website opened in Safari. I've slightly edited my question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the app or site you're pasting into doesn't support image paste, and so is defaulting to pasting the link.

You can test by copying and then pasting the image into something like Microsoft Word or Pages, where the actual image should appear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the app supports this feature. I've been always doing it on Chrome  on Windows. The funny thing is it also does not work on Mac's Chrome.

Comment: For whatever reason macOS copies both the image and URL when you use "copy image", no matter the software. And the target software chooses which to paste from the clipboard. It makes sense in many cases for the target software to pick text over image, so knowing this it makes no sense for macOS to offer both "copy image" and "copy image address" but have them both copy the URL. The user knows what they are doing when they select between those two options, so the software should respect that. This problem has persisted for over a decade, probably thanks to a single stubborn manager at Apple.

Answer (score 1):

My version of Safari, 12.01, does not copy an image from a webpage. It just copies the link. What you have to do is right click on the image you wish to copy and select download image. You can then open the image in preview and copy it or you can upload an image to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since when this became possible but you now have two different options for image copying:

- Copy Image Address - copies the URL of the image
- Copy Image - copies the actual image

[image: Screenshot of the menu when right-clicking on an image (Safari 16.6 macOS 13.6)]

<sub>FYI, I'm on macOS 13.6 using Safari 16.6</sub>